# Functions and functors as arguments to template functions

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I'm looking for a way to pass function pointers, functors or lambdas to a template function `g` which uses the passed function's argument types, for example:

```
template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
struct wrapper_t {
  boost::function<void(T1,T2,T3)> f;
  wrapper_t( boost::function<void(T1,T2,T3)> f ) : f(f) {}
  void operator( std::vector<T1> &a, std::vector<T2> &b, T3 c ) {
    assert(a.size() == b.size());
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i != a.size() ; i++) f(a[i], b[i], c);
  }
};
template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
wrapper_t<T1,T2,T3> make_wrapper( boost::function<void(T1,T2,T3)> f ) {
  return wrapper_t<T1,T2,T3>( f );
}

void f(int, double, char) {};
wrapper_t<int, double, char> w0(f); // need to repeat types

auto w1 = make_wrapper(f); // more comfortable

std::vector<int> a{{1, 2, 3}};
std::vector<double> b{{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}};
w0( a, b, 'c' );
w1( a, b, 'c' );
```

The `make_wrapper` function only exists to extract the types from the argument, some syntactic sugar to avoid having to type them twice.

---

A minimal example for my problem is this function:

```
template<class T>
void g1( const boost::function<void(T)> & ) {}
```

Using these as input

```
void f1(int) {}
struct f2_t { void operator()(int) {} };
```

it fails to infer `T=int`

```
f2_t f2;
g1( f1 ); // mismatched types ‘const std::function<void(T)>’ and ‘void(int)’
g1( f2 ); // ‘f2_t’ is not derived from ‘const std::function<void(T)>’
g1( [](int){} ); // ‘::<lambda(int)>’ is not derived from ‘…
g1<int>( f1 ); // ok
g1<int>( f2 ); // ok
g1<int>( [](int){} ); // ok
```

But `T=int` can be inferred from a plain function pointer, but of this doesn't work with the functor or lambda either:

```
template<class T>
void g2( void (*)(T) ) {}

g2( f1 ); // ok
g2( f2 ); // mismatched types …
g2<int>( f2 ); // ok
g2( [](int){} ); // mismatched types …
g2<int>( [](int){} ); // ok
```

*Is there a way to infer `T` not just for plain function pointers but for functors and lambdas, too?*

Or does it have to be something like this?

```
template<class F>
void g( F ) { typedef first_argument_of<F>::type T; }
```

(in my real code I need to deconstruct a function with four arguments this way, but `std::function::…argument_type` only exists for one or two arguments; `boost::function` has argN_type, but I don't think I can use that anyway since `F` is not always a `function` which is my problem, see above, etc)

Comment: Curious: where are you getting your `T` from to feed this `template` deduced `std::function<void(T)>` in order to invoke it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose I read in a comment that the OP really wants to take a function that mutates a `T`, and turn it into a function that mutates a `std::vector<T>`, and thinks that in order to do this you need to know what `T` is.

[You don't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=940673d6a3896e238189b1fc4f71819c-f0d9bbac4ab033ac5f4ce440d21735ee)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename Lambda>
struct container_version {
  Lambda closure;
  container_version( container_version const& ) = default;
  container_version( container_version && ) = default;
  container_version( container_version & ) = default;

  template<typename U>
  container_version( U&& func ):closure(std::forward<U>(func)) {};

  // lets make this work on any iterable range:
  template<typename Container>
  void operator()( Container&& c ) const {
    for( auto&& x:c )
      closure(x);
  }
};

template<typename Lambda>
container_version< typename std::decay<Lambda>::type >
make_container_version( Lambda&& closure ) {
  return {std::forward<Lambda>(closure)};
}

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <array>

int main() {
   std::vector<int> my_vec = {0, 1, 2, 3};
   for (auto x:my_vec)
      std::cout << x << ",";
   std::cout << "\n";
   make_container_version( []( int& x ) { x++; })( my_vec );

   for (auto x:my_vec)
      std::cout << x << ",";
   std::cout << "\n";

   // hey look, we can store it in a `std::function` if we need to:
   auto super_func = make_container_version( []( int& x ) { x++; } );
   std::function< void( std::vector<int>& ) > func = super_func;
   // and the same super_func can be used for a function on a different container:
   std::function< void( std::array<int,7>& ) > func2 = super_func;

   func(my_vec);
   for (auto x:my_vec)
      std::cout << x << ",";
   std::cout << "\n";
}
```

In fact, taking the argument and turning it into a `std::function`, or forcing it to be stored in a `std::function`, costs efficiency, increases the complexity of the code, and makes it  unable to do things that it has no problem doing.

The above version, before it is packed into a `std::function`, can operate on `set`s, `list`s, `vector`s , raw `C` arrays, `std::array`s, etc.

Comment: you're right, I was making this a lot more complicated than it needed to be; didn't occur to me that the wrapper itself could be a template too…

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do what you want for a variety of reasons. But here is one that should make the problem pretty clear:

```
struct function_object
{
    template<typename ...T>
    void operator ()(T&&... v){}
};

f( function_object{} );
```

What is the type of the arguments of the function object passed to `f`? There isn't any, it can be called with any kind and number of arguments.

Comment: +1; to elaborate a bit more, C++ doesn't support the combination of `virtual` style polymorphism, implemented by `std::function`, with `template` style generic polymorphism, implemented by `std::bind`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: What now? It most certainly does, or I am not understanding at all what you are saying... could you rephrase that?

Comment: @K You can't put a templated functor inside a `std::function` without determining all the template arguments. You can `std::bind` a `std::function` but the result is a new, uniquely-determined type, not runtime polymorphic.

Comment: I don't understand how that relates to my problem where the `void operator()(int)` isn't a template though?

Comment: (I think tagging it as C++11 was misleading, it's exactly the same in C++03 if you replace `std::function` with `boost::function`)

Comment: @pascal: Some situation, what would you do if `f2_t` had a `void operator()(float)` overload besides `void operator()(int)`?

Comment: @pascal: The thing is: How would the compiler know which type to deduce `T` to? *Anything* would potentially be a perfect match.

Comment: @pascal the language does not care about your situation. The language cannot support this in general so it keeps consistency here.

Comment: In other words, for the language to support this it would require adding it explicitly as an exception to the rules, which is undesirable both from a language design point of view but also from a user's point of view (the more rules your language has the harder it is to reason about the programs you write in it.

Comment: Ok, I expected an error only in the ambiguous case, but this is quite special so I understand why it would be easier this way

Answer (score 2):

I also think there is no direct way to define the template parameters and function arguments of a single, primary template definition such that `T` can be deduced in all the different situations (function pointer, lambda expression, `std::function` argument etc.).

I would therefore recommend that you follow the approach suggested at the end of your question. Indeed neither `std::function` nor the tools offered by Boost (as far as I know) will easily enable this, though.

What I use (and I learnt that from other SO posts in the past), is a rather complicated template `function_traits` with specializations for all the different cases. My definition is this:

```
template <typename T>
struct function_traits
  : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{ };

template <typename Return, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<Return(Args...)>
{
  typedef std::size_t size_type;
  typedef Return      result_type;
  typedef result_type function_type(Args...);

  static constexpr size_type arity = sizeof...(Args);


  template <size_type index>
  struct arg
  {
    typedef typename std::tuple_element<index,std::tuple<Args...>>::type type;
  };

  static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename Return, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<Return(*)(Args...)>
  : function_traits<Return(Args...)>
{ };

template <typename Return, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<Return(&)(Args...)>
  : function_traits<Return(Args...)>
{ };

template <typename Class, typename Return, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<Return(Class::*)(Args...)>
  : function_traits<Return(Args...)>
{ };

template <typename Class, typename Return, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<Return(Class::*)(Args...) volatile>
  : function_traits<Return(Args...)>
{ };

template <typename Class, typename Return, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<Return(Class::*)(Args...) const>
  : function_traits<Return(Args...)>
{ };

template <typename Class, typename Return, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<Return(Class::*)(Args...) const volatile>
  : function_traits<Return(Args...)>
{ };
```

To make using this even more convenient, you may want to define `using`-aliases:

```
template <typename Fun>
using result_of = typename function_traits<Fun>::result_type;

template <typename Fun, std::size_t index>
using arg = typename function_traits<Fun>::template arg<index>::type;
```

With all these definitions (which in the below, I assume you put into a separate header `more_type_traits.hpp`), you can then easily define your wrapper function as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include "more_type_traits.hpp"

template <typename Fun>
using noref = typename std::remove_reference<Fun>::type;

template <typename Fun>
result_of<noref<Fun>> fun(Fun &&argfun)
{
  // Default-initialize the first argument
  arg<noref<Fun>,0> arg {};

  // Call the function
  return argfun(arg);
}
```

The below (which is basically copied from your code) then compiles and works for me:

```
void f1(int i)
{ std::cout << "f1(" << i << ')' << std::endl; }

struct f2_t
{
  void operator()(int i)
  { std::cout << "f2(" << i << ')' << std::endl; }
};


int main()
{
  fun(f1);

  f2_t f2;
  fun(f2);

  std::function<void(int)> funobj = [](int i)
    { std::cout << "funobj(" << i << ')' << std::endl; };
  fun(funobj);

  fun( [](int i) { std::cout << "lambda(" << i << ')' << std::endl; } ); 

  return 0;
}
```

Clearly, the definition of `function_traits` is complicated, because many different specializations are required. But it's worth the effort if you want to make function wrapping convenient.

Comment: This `function_traits` is not complicated enough. It is less general than `std::result_of`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I didn't say it's perfect. What parts are missing anyway?

Comment: My point is not about it being perfect but about it not being more generally applicable than `std::result_of` which leads me to "why would I ever use this instead of std::result_of?" To see what it misses see k-ballo's answer or any polymorphic function object like `std::greater <>`. I don't see a point in making life way harder for users of those just to gain... I'm not sure what.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes The question isn't about deriving the type of the result, but of the arguments. Including the result type in the function-traits class above is just an easy win.

Comment: @jogojapan: And nobody cares about the argument types, since they may well be polymorphic. You only care if "this function-like entity called with these arguments" produces the right result.

Comment: @Xeo Well, the questioner wanted to do derive the argument types. There is no explanation of why exactly that's necessary in the question. Are you saying there is never a reason to get an explicit representation of the types of arguments of a function?

Comment: What I need this for is a wrapper generator, for example you pass it a `void f(T)` and it returns a `void(std::vector<T> v)` functor, where `f` is applied to each element of `v`.

Comment: @pascal and comments like that is why you should post your actual, practical problem.  Because there is *no need for argument type deduction* in order to do what you want to do: what more, doing it your way costs efficiency.

Comment: @Yakk To clarify one thing: There can be very good reasons for extracting argument types from a function passed as template argument. One example is `static_assert` type checks for whether the function meets certain restrictions. Since concepts are not quite available yet, this can be part of a strategy to get readable error messages early on when unsuitable functions are passed.

Comment: @jogojapan I am sure there is: but even your example, is not asking "can it take a `T`" rather than "can it only take a `T`" a better idea?

Comment: @Yakk Not necessarily. But even if so, `std::decay`, `std::is_base_of` and the like can be used to facilitate static checks.

Comment: I wrote that before noticing Yakk's answer which solved my problem